# Annotation syntax error when migrating from 2.2.x to 3.x

Tags: django

I am in the process of migrating from Django 2.2 to 3.2. After fixing most deprecation issues, an annotation I rely on throughout my project is throwing a syntax error. It does not appear to matter which 3.x version I use, and this annotation has worked throughout most of 2.2.x's versions:

```
Journal.objects.annotate(
    p_user=F('assignment__courses__participation__user'),
    can_have_journal=F('assignment__courses__participation__role__can_have_journal'),
).filter(
    Q(assignment__is_group_assignment=True) | Q(p_user__in=F('authors__user'), can_have_journal=True),
)
```

This yields the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ""VLE_assignmentparticipation""
LINE 1: ...ave_journal" AND "VLE_participation"."user_id" IN "VLE_assig...
```

Part of the trace:

```
venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:317: in __getitem__
    qs._fetch_all()
venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:1324: in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:51: in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:1169: in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py:434: in execute
    return real_execute(self, sql, params)
venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:66: in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:75: in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:84: in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py:90: in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
```

For good measure a [link to the models file](https://github.com/eJourn-al/eJournal/blob/develop/src/django/VLE/models.py)

If I eliminate the or in the filter block: `| Q(p_user__in=F('authors__user'), can_have_journal=True)`, the annotation works without issues.

I cannot find anything in the release/deprecation notes about annotations changing, does anyone have a recommendation on what the underlying issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the related [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31135) (also see [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32752#comment:1))

The SQL syntax error is rather unfriendly for behavior that functioned throughout 2.2.x.

For the posted code snippet this will resolve the issue whilst mainting the SQL: `p_user__in=F('authors__user')` -> `p_user=F('authors__user')`